# Обработка принятых данных из сети . Netty библиотека

Tags: javafx, клиент-сервер, netty

При нажатии кнопки в форме JavaFX на сервер отправляется запрос, который возвращает булеву переменную, после чего требуется запустить в зависимости от значения этой переменной другую форму. Проблема в том, что когда приходит ответ с сервера, форма зависает и вообще не понятно как передать данную переменную в класс где обрабатывается форма из метода channelReadComplete0, так как он не завершается а метод channelReadComplete является наследуемым от класса библиотеки.

В классе контролере при нажатии:

```
public class Controller{
Client client=new Client(user);
client.runs();
//Не понимаю как сюда вернуть переменную полученную от сервера и запустить нужную форму.
}

public class Client{
 User user;
  Channel channel;
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        public Client(User user){
        this.user=user;
        public void runs()   {
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler((new SmartHouseClientInitializer()));

            channel = b.connect("127.0.0.1", 9989).sync().channel();

            SmartHouseClientHandler handler =            channel.pipeline().get(SmartHouseClientHandler.class);
            ArrayList<Object>convert=convert(user);
            addUser (channel,convert);
           handler.addUser(channel, convert,this);
            channel.close();//До этого места программа не доходит то есть      метод addUser не завершается

 public class SmartHouseClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    @Override
         protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) throws Exception {
             s=(Boolean)o;
             System.out.println ("Получил "+s);

           //если здесь создаю экземпляр класса где лежит primarystage то метод
           // запускается но не запускает форму!
                  }
```

Comment: А как ты его создаешь? Ты вызываешь метод Application.launch(args)?

Comment: public  boolean showrez(Boolean s){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation (Main.class.getResource("reg.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

             Create the dialog Stage.
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Create User");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);    
            dialogStage.showAndWait();

Comment: в методе main стандартно прописано  launch(args где открывается первоначальная форма  которая привязана к контроллеру выше, в этом же главном классе с методом main есть еще метод который и должен загружать вторую форму после ответа сервера.
Программа этот метод вызывает если банально вывод в консоль текста прописать она работает, а форму не рисует почему то!)хотя примаристейдж один и если я просто напрямую вызываю то форма  загружается.